# Online Excel Add In on workbook re-opening

Tags: office365, office-js

We have a Task Pane  Add-In for Excel Online.

Installing the Add-In from the Office Store open the sidebar with our IFRAME as expected.

But when we close the tab with the spreadsheet and reopen the same workbook (for edit or not) later, only an icon appears on the right border. Sometimes this is our Add-In icon, sometimes it is a neutral icon (mouse over Office-Addin). Clicking on the icon does not show the sidebar (although it has been loaded). Pressing the arrow above the icon(s) does not help either.

The same thing happens with other Task Pane Add-Ins.

Sometime we can insert our Add-In again (and it works then), sometime we can't (ie we are allowed to insert it, but the UI does not change).

The behavior can be reproduces on Chrome 47, Firefox 41 and Edge.

Whats wrong there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm delighted to say that the fix for the Excel Add-In issue  should be live on Wednesday 4th of November at the latest.

We really appreciate you taking the time to post the question as it has directly resulted in the fix.

Thanks

Keith

Microsoft Snt. Engnieer

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting this issue and giving us the opportunity to find a resolution.
It looks like we are having a temporary issue at present where the Office Addins width is getting saved to 3 pixels. We are striving to find a resolution as soon as possible. In the mean time you can try the following workaround

Temporary workarounds:

1. Opening the file in excel client app and saving the file will fix the width issue because we have a minimum width set in excel client app.

After the file is edited in client or excel client, excel client respects the new value and it do NOT go back to value

We will update the article once it is fixed

Thanks
Keith

Microsoft Snr Engineer.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I don't think that the proposed workaround is something we could successfully communicate to our non technical customers.  (How, the customers doesn't see our iframe when the issue occurs and he wouldn't use Excel Online if he has to use Excel Desktop or even an XML editor ). So we (and all the other Add-In developers) will have to wait for the real MS solution.

Comment: Point taken, I have fixed that up and I should have good news with regard to the fix. The root cause has been identified and a fix is going out. I will revert when I have a date you will find it.