# Automatic loading of Excel add-ins with Add-in Commands

Tags: office365, office-js

As mentioned here (https://dev.office.com/blogs/make-your-add-ins-available-in-the-office-ribbon) all new taskpane submissions to the Office store must use commands to pass validation.

After experimentation with add-ins with and without commands, it appears that existing add-ins *without* commands will automatically reload when the file is re-opened in Excel online (e.g. via OneDrive, Dropbox).  Add-ins *with* commands ***do not*** reload upon re-opening the file, and must be re-installed through the add-in store each time the file is opened.

I know there have been similar questions asked here:

- [Online Excel Add In on workbook re-opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254598/online-excel-add-in-on-workbook-re-opening?rq=1)
- [Automatically loading Word Task Pane Office Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307607/automatically-loading-word-task-pane-office-add-in?rq=1)
- [Keep Office add-in task pane open at document load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379427/keep-office-add-in-task-pane-open-at-document-load)

And perhaps more specifically here:

- [Office Web App - Show task pane on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359620/office-web-app-show-task-pane-on-load/39376680#39376680) where the suggestion is to *remove* add-in commands.

Given that I cannot submit an add-in without add-in commands any more, how can I have the add-in persist / show up in the ribbon on subsequent re-opening of the file (currently our add-in users have to constantly re-install the add-in) ?

Comment: I don't have concrete details to share yet, but you are correct in your analysis of today's behavior, and we do have a solution for this problem forthcoming.  Let me contact the team to see if they can provide more details.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft can you point us to an example, documentation, and/or a blog post that explains how to do this going forward for Word, Excel and Outlook? Much appreciated.

Comment: Sure.  I believe there may, in fact, already be a sample/article.  Let me forward this to the right contacts on the team…

Comment: Hi Michael, Wondering if you had a chance to find the sample/article.  Also looking how to get an add-in persisted for files stored on a  cloud storage partner.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a topic about this: [Automatically open a task pane with a document](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document). And a sample at: [Office OOXML EmbedAddin](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin)